# Cannot check in related tables in ArcPad?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-database, arcpad

I'm using ArcPad Data Manager (ArcMap 10) to check in data in axf file. I can check in feature layers, but I can't check in related tables and the feature class parent of the related tables.

I have tried changing the `[AXF_STATUS]` to 1 in the parent feature layer and in its child related table, but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several tests in the process of check out - check in, I discovered that I have a related table named 'user'. This table couldn't be checked in and its parent couldn't, either. So, I've changed 'user' to 'utilisateur' and it works :D. So, 'user' is a keyword that should be avoided in geodatabase design.